# CRON job to run on the last week of the month

Tags: c#, .net, cron, scheduler, quartz.net

I need to create a CRON job to run on LAST week of the month and then the day of the week and time.

I got the fourth week to work, that is expression for it: f*ourth week, Sunday, 12:00*

```
0 0 12 ? 1/1 SUN#4 *
```

What I need is: *last week, Friday, 12:00*

I tried `0 0 3 L * ?` but that will run on last day of the month.

[image]

[CroneMakerHelper](http://www.cronmaker.com/;jsessionid=node0w8yxwaauokz6dzstd65c866l196697.node0?0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error here is a solution for CRON job to run on the every last week of the month

```
0 00 12 ? * 6L
```

This expressions means: run every last week of the month, Friday, 12:00

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the friday and use condition to check if it is last friday, like below

> 0 0 * * 5 root run-if-today L